# Find customers whose fist name and last name are not unique

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a customer table with id, first_name and last_name. I need to show all the customers whose first and last names are not unique in the table as well as the number of times each first and last name pair appears in the table.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` will find you unique data. For a full query, you'd  need to specify your SQL flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(*)
FROM customers
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```